# Dummie: MacOS: Need to remove lien in certain files into a directory

Tags: macos

I need some help and even I have found many information here I can't finish solving my issue. I'm using Mac with Catalina.

I have one directory with many text files.
In some of then, I have to remove the lines contain a string '00048817202'.

Based on different post, I have tried the command:

```
for f in *.txt ; do grep -v '00048817202' $f > $f ; done
```

My pain point, I can't read and write into the same file, but I don't find a simple way to add a suffix in my output file.

Perhaps, someone could help me, Thanks in advance,
Philippe

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it myself :)

’’’

```
for f in *.txt ;do grep -v '00048817202' $f > filename ; mv filename $f ; done
```

’’’

So I copy to a temporary file and move it in my original name. It's worked!